# PHP foreach always returns 01-01-1970 when empty

Tags: php, foreach

I could see that this issue was tackled a several times, I have read carefully all threads but could find a solution for my problem.

Here is the code that's returned 01-01-1970 when empty :

```
    $candidateid = '{gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment___id}'; 
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query ->select (array('gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat.date_exa_2')) ->from('gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment') ->leftJoin('gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment_repeat_choix_formation ON gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment.id = gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment_repeat_choix_formation.parent_id') ->leftJoin('gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat ON gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment_repeat_choix_formation.choix_formation = gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat.id') ->leftJoin('gprh_fabrik_user_training ON gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat.parent_id = gprh_fabrik_user_training.id') ->having('gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment.id = ' .         $db->quote($candidateid)) ->group('gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment.id, gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat.date_exa_2');
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $row = $db->loadObjectList();
    foreach ($row as $item) { return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($item->date_exa_2)); };
```

Would appreciate some help here. Thanks in advance. Cheers, Marc

Comment: `strtotime($item->date_exa_2)` [is returning false](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and `date()` assumes this as the integer `0`. double check `$item->date_exa_2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix it. You just need to check that `$item->date_exa_2` is not empty before passing to `strtotime()`

```
foreach($row as $item) {
    return (!empty($item->date_exa_2)) ? date('d-m-Y', strtotime($item->date_exa_2)) : '';
}
```

Comment: Hi Ryan thank for your fix, it is working like a charm and your code is reduced, so perfect, thanks for your time, cheers, marc
PS: tomas answer is working also well

Comment: Do you know why this works? When a field is empty, strtotime will think its its false (zero) and zero equates to 1-1-1970 in unix timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

**Date Function :**

date('Format','Timestamp');

Timestamp is a count which starts at the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970. Therefore, the timestamp is merely the number of seconds between a particular date and the Unix Epoch.

When $item->date_exa_2 is empty then strtotime($item->date_exa_2) returns 0 (0 seconds from Unix Epoch) and date function returns 01-01-1970.

**Try this**

```
foreach ($row as $item){ 
    $time = strtotime($item->date_exa_2);
    if($time){
        return date('d-m-Y', $time); 
    }else{
        return '';
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Tomas, thanks a lot too for your answer which is working perfectly. I choose Ryan code since it is reduced. Thanks anyway for your time too, cheers, marc